# Finding a polynomial $P_n (x)$ such that $e^{1/x^2}\int _0^xe^{-1/t^2}dt=P_n(x)+o(x^{2n+2})$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Find a polynomial $P_n (x)$, such that $$ e^{1/x^2} \int _0 ^x e^{-1/t^2} dt = P_n(x) + o(x ^ {2n+2}) \quad\text{as}\; x\to 0.$$

I try to simplify the integral by putting $t=xs$, and then use the Taylor extension, but the integral of each item of the series is infinity. Then I try to decomposition the integral into two parts to make sure the integral is infinity. But I cannot solve the $P_n(x)$.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: You can develop the asymptotic series using repeated integration by parts: $e^{-1/t^2}=\frac{t^3}{2}\frac{d}{dt} e^{-1/t^2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is a good and efficient idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \int _0 ^x e^{-1/t^2} dt =x\:e^{-1/x^2}-\sqrt{\pi}\:\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \tag 1$$
$$ e^{1/x^2} \int _0 ^x e^{-1/t^2} dt =x-\sqrt{\pi}\:e^{1/x^2}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \tag 2$$
The asymptotic expansion of erfc($X$) which is known can be found in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion .
$$\text{erfc}(X)\simeq\frac{1}{X\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-X^2}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2X^2)^n} \right)\qquad X\to\infty \tag 3$$
With $X=\frac{1}{x}$ and $x\to 0$ :
$$\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-1/x^2}\left(x+\sum_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}x^{2n+1} \right)\tag 4$$
Putting into Eq.$(2)$ and after simplification :
$$\boxed{ e^{1/x^2} \int _0 ^x e^{-1/t^2} dt \simeq\sum_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}x^{2n+1}}\qquad x\to 0.$$
Double factorial : $(2n-1)!!=1*3*5*...*(2n-3)*(2n-1)\qquad$ $(n>0)$.

$e^{1/x^2} \int _0 ^x e^{-1/t^2} dt \simeq \frac12 x^3-\frac34 x^5+\frac{15}{8}x^7-...\qquad x\to 0.$

Note : This is also related to the Dawson integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^xe^{-1/t^2}dt=\int e^{-1/x^2}dx+C_0$$
but from taking $\lim_{t\to0^+}e^{-1/t^2}=0$ you can show $C_0=0$ . Now we can use the fact that:
$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\,\,\,\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$$ so (I will now neglect the integration constant):
$$\int e^{-1/x^2}dx=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{-2n}}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{1-2n}}{(1-2n)n!}$$
so we have an exponential multiplied by a polynomial but not a polynomial alone.

Comment: Doing the integral by part as the comment above is good enough.